# Difference between the respondent's cholesterol level and maximum blood pressure. Is this a paired t-test?

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

This is probably an easy question, but wanted to confirm before I start doing the analysis for my intro stats course...

So a question I have to answer is as below:

> Test the difference between the respondent's cholesterol level and
> maximum blood pressure. If so, write the difference.

As I understand paired/dependent t-test are for the same subject, however most of the time they are the same measure (ie. before/after). However the two variables I have been given are totally different (continuous) measures... Is this still a paired t-test?

[Data example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXFCb.png)

Comment: If you have a table of data, there may be a column with the differences explicitly written making it paired.

Comment: Unfortunately there is not. I have added a picture of the data I was given

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A paired t-test is used when the difference between the two variables is specific to the subject/sample-point. More specifically, we use it when we expect there to be *some* correlation between the variables that is *subject specific*. When the two variables are totally independent we use a two sample t-test.

So if your question said something like: ‘Is the average cholesterol level and maximum blood pressure significantly different in this population?’ And if your data from cholesterol level and blood pressure came from two different random samples, then I would say a non-paired test.

However, your question specifically said “the respondents” which tells me you have one sample with two variables.  You know both the cholesterol level and blood pressure level for a single respondent.  Furthermore, this is health data related to the heart, there is likely a correlation within respondents.

Comment: OK, so regardless if they are totally different measures/means we are comparing to, it is a paired t-test if it is the same subject?

Comment: It typically is if you have the same subject.  There are also instances when they are different subjects but it still a paired t-test (matched pairs).